# Change the Skin of the Designer for Windows Mobile In VS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, compact-framework

Is there a way to change the skin you see in Visual Studio from the standard form?

I have a skin I use for my emulator.  I would like to see that skin in my Visual Studio designers.

Anyone know a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can - and it's pretty easy.  The challenge is *finding* the skin files, as Microsoft puts them all over the damned place.

For the newer WinMo stuff (5.0 and later), look here:

`%Program Files%\Windows Mobile 6 SDK\PocketPC\Deviceemulation`

For the older stuff, look here:

`%Program Files%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\SmartDevices\Skins`

For non mobile CE devices look here:

`%Program Files%\Windows CE Tools\wce600\{platform name}\Emulation\Skins`

You'll see images for the skins and an XML file that describes the skin and where the emulated buttons are.

Id' recommend going into your device configuration in Studio, selecting an existing one and doing a "Save As" and then mucking around with the copy you create instead of the original.

Comment: That worked!  Thanks.  My Solid black is showing up as white inside of VS.  Have you ever seen that issue?  I don't have much solid black, so I can live with it, if there is no way to fix it.